# UPDATE table_name SET col_name = varchar WHERE col_name is NULL;

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, string-constant

The following UPDATE fails :-

```
UPDATE table_name SET col_name = varchar WHERE col_name is NULL;
```

The failure message is :-

```
ERROR:  column "varchar" does not exist
```

Whereas the undermentioned one succeeds :-

```
UPDATE table_name SET col_name = 889977 WHERE col_name is NULL;
```

I have checked the `pg_typeof` of the column - col_name is  `character varying`. Kindly help.

Comment: If "`varchar`" is supposed to be a string literal, enclose it in single quotes: `'varchar'`. Otherwise your statement doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @sticky bit --- Yes thats the issue - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you missed quote for string

```
UPDATE table_name SET col_name = 'varchar' WHERE col_name is NULL;
```